# Alias "git git" to just "git"?

Tags: git

Every now and then I wind up typing "`git`" then think of something else, then type e.g., "`git checkout master`". Of course, this leaves me with

```
$ git git checkout master
git: 'git' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
    init
$
```

Is there a way to create a git alias named `git` that is a no-op? I've tried the obvious like "`git = ''`" and "`git = ""`" and "`git = " "`" but not surprisingly, they all result in responses like `Expansion of alias 'git' failed; '' is not a git command`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured out the answer:

Add this alias to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    git = "!git"
```

**Old answer for posterity**

Rather than alias, you just need to have script named `git-git` in your path with the contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
git "$@"
```

so when you say "`git git`", git looks for `git-git`, and passes the remaining arguments to it. Of course, by recursion, you can be very absent minded and say "`git`" as many times as you like:

```
$ git git git git git git git git git git git git status # <- still works
```

Update:
Yesterday I hit enter on `gitgit status`. So, while you are at it, may as well symlink `git-git` to `gitgit`. That doesn't chain indefinitely, but still.

Comment: Any nasty side effects you can think of?

Comment: I can't think of any. It would have to be something destructive that could easily be misspelled as "git" right?

Comment: I don't know. I was just asking. +1 anyway.

Comment: The only side effect I could see if git ever adds a git command, which is very unlikely.

Comment: Anyone think git would suggest a patch for this, adding `git-git.sh`?